# Android YoutubePlayer API crash

Tags: java, android, api, youtube

i have created an android application that uses the youtube API however i am facing a problem.
when I load a fragment with the youtube video. load another fragment then go back to the fragment with the youtube video the application is crashing.

Fragment that plays the video :

```
public static Fragment newInstance(Context context) {
    WorkshopFragment f = new WorkshopFragment();
    return f;
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.workshop_fragment, null);

    YouTubePlayerFragment youTubePlayerFragment = (YouTubePlayerFragment) getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youtube_fragment);
    youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(API_KEY, this);

    return root; 
}

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(Provider arg0,
        YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) {

}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,
        boolean wasRestored) {
      if (!wasRestored) {
            player.cueVideo(VIDEO_ID);
          }
}
```

}

layout :

```
 <fragment
  android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment"
  android:layout_below="@+id/paragraph"
  android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
  android:id="@+id/youtube_fragment"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

**Fixed Duplicate Id Error**:

XML :

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_youtube"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rule"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />
```

i then created the youtube fragment via code :

```
Fragment fragment = new YouTubePlayerFragment();
FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.fragment_youtube, fragment);
ft.commit(); 

YouTubePlayerFragment youtubeFrag = (YouTubePlayerFragment) fragment;
youtubeFrag.initialize(API_KEY, this);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the fragment is in XML, so every time you inflate the XML it makes a new fragment. And i think the id of the fragment is not changing in the XML, and it is trying to create the new fragment with the same id as there is already one running. Two running fragments cant have the same id, so i think the app crashes.

Try to kill thr old fragment before starting a new one or create the fragment programmatically and not through xml .

Comment: i achieved this by creating the fragment programmatically in the end. thanks for the help